# Integer partition algorithms

Tags: combinatorics

I am familiar with and have written MathCad algorithms for the partition functions (,),which gives the number of ways of partitioning  into   parts, (,), which gives the number of ways of partitioning  into   distinct parts, and (,,), which gives the number of ways of partitioning  into exactly  parts of size at most . I seek a recursive algorithm for (,,), which gives the number of ways of partitioning   into **exactly**  **distinct** parts of size at most . If there is an existing python algorithm, all the better. Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is answered on Math SE: [Counting integer partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts with size at most $M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646705/counting-integer-partitions-of-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts-size-at-most-m).